How can i change default list view for custom object
I have a custom object called "Customer Successes".  I can not figure out how to change the view so that when i click on the tab at top, i see the view selected in image.  Currently, I have to click "Go!" everytime.  I want "Customer Success Meetings" to be the default view.
Thanks in advance


In the normal Classic mode, you can't override or default this page to go into your default view. You can either create a new Classic Console, or switch to Lightning Experience.
